# Join 3 Tables on ID's but display other columns in Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Users enter in a first and/or last name of a single client they are searching for. Search will result in multiple records which are displayed in an Array. The desired effect would be to have the array contains some columns from the client table and a school name and a cip name from the school and cip tables. Array left joins these 3 tables on ID. How do I join these 3 tables on ID but display the school name and cip name from their tables?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (
   client LEFT JOIN school ON school_school_id = school_id) 
   LEFT JOIN cip ON client_cip1 = cip_id 
   WHERE client_id = ".$client_ID_Array[0];
```

Here is some coding for the array
`<td width="145" scope="col"> <?php echo $clientRow['client_first_name'] ?> </td>
 <td width="152" scope="col"> <?php echo $clientRow['client_cip1'] ?> </td>
 <td width="152" scope="col"> <?php echo $clientRow['school_school_id'] ?> </td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the following query:

```
SELECT c.client_id, s.school_id, cip.cip_id FROM client AS c
LEFT JOIN school AS s ON c.school_id = s.school_id 
LEFT JOIN cip ON c.cip_id = cip.cip_id
WHERE c.client_id = 7;
```

I'll get as results `client_id` from `client` table, `school_id` from `school` and `cip_id` from `cip`.

When I type `c.client_id` I'm asking to retrieve `client_id` field from `c` table, where `c` has been defined using the phrase `clients AS c`.

So if you want to select `school_name` from `school` you will have to add after `SELECT` keyword: `s.school_name`.